# How to identify unhealthy pods in a statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a StatefulSet with 6 replicas.

All of a sudden StatefulSet thinks there are 5 ready replicas out if 6. When I look at the pod status all 6 pods are ready with all the readiness checks passed `1/1`.

Now I am trying to find logs or status that shows which pod is unhealthy as per the StatefulSet, so I could debug further.

Where can I find information or logs for the StatefulSet that could tell me which pod is unhealthy? I have already checked the output of `describe pods` and `describe statefulset` but none of them show which pod is unhealthy.

Comment: Try describing the pods and StatefulSet.

Comment: If one of your statefulset pods are unhealty then you should kubectl describe pod my-unhealty-statefulset and check Kube Events, section to see error. If there is no error then you should check pod logs instead.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say you created next statefulset:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    user: anurag
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      user: anurag # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 6 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        user: anurag # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Result is:

```
kubectl get StatefulSet web -o wide
NAME   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES
web    6/6     8m31s   nginx        k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
```

What we can also check  `StatefulSet`'s status in:

```
kubectl get statefulset web -o yaml
status:
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 6
  currentRevision: web-599978b754
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 6
  replicas: 6
  updateRevision: web-599978b754
  updatedReplicas: 6
```

As per [Debugging a StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-stateful-set/#debugging-a-statefulset), you can list all the pods which belong to a current StatefulSet using labels.

```
$  kubectl get pods -l user=anurag
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0   1/1     Running   0          13m
web-1   1/1     Running   0          12m
web-2   1/1     Running   0          12m
web-3   1/1     Running   0          12m
web-4   1/1     Running   0          12m
web-5   1/1     Running   0          11m
```

Here, at this point, if any of your pods aren't available- you will definitely  see that. And next debugging is [Debug Pods and ReplicationControllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-stateful-set/#debugging-a-statefulset) including checks if you have  enough sufficient resources to start all these pods and etc etc.

Describe problematic pod (`kubectl describe pod web-0`) should give you an answer why that happened in the very end in Events section.

---

For example, if you will use origin yaml as it is for this example from [statefulset components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components) -  you will have an error and  any of your pods will up and running. (The reason is `storageClassName: "my-storage-class"` )

The exact error and understanding what is happening comes from describing problematic pod... that's how it works.

```
kubectl describe pod web-0
vents:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  31s (x2 over 31s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```